# Roman numbers including lastpage

Tags: roman-numerals, lastpage

In my report i use the function \lastpage. This works fine in the mainmatter, but it takes the lastpage of the mainmatter and not the lastpage of the frontmatter and inserts it.

So in my table of content, I have my page iii of 19. Here it should be page iii of iii instead of. Anyone who knows how to make a solution to this problem.

```
%%%% PAKKER %%%%

% ¤¤ Oversaettelse og tegnsaetning ¤¤ %
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                 % Input-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. input fra keyboard, tegnoversigt eller andet (UTF8 = Unicode)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                    % Output-indkodning af tegnsaet, dvs. printede fonte og tegn (T1 = Type 1 font med support for de fleste europaeiske sprog)
\usepackage[danish]{babel}                  % Sproglig fremstilling af elementer (figur vs. figure, litteratur vs. bibliography osv.)
\usepackage{ragged2e,anyfontsize}           % Justering af elementer

% ¤¤ Figurer og tabeller (floats) ¤¤ %
\usepackage{graphicx}                       % Inkludering af eksterne billeder (JPG, PNG, PDF)
\usepackage{multirow}                       % Fletning af raekker og kolonner (\multicolumn og \multirow)
\usepackage{colortbl}                       % Farver i tabeller (fx \columncolor, \rowcolor og \cellcolor)
\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}             % Definer farver med \definecolor. Se mere: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Colors
\usepackage{flafter}                        % Soerger for, at floats ikke optraeder i teksten foer deres reference
\usepackage{float}                          % Muliggoer eksakt placering af floats, fx \begin{figure}[H]
\let\newfloat\relax                         % Justering mellem float-pakken og memoir
%\usepackage{eso-pic}                       % Tilfoej billedekommandoer paa hver side
%\usepackage{wrapfig}                       % Indsaettelse af figurer omsvoebt af tekst 
%\usepackage{multicol}                      % Muliggoer tekst i spalter
%\usepackage{rotating}                      % Rotation af tekst med \begin{sideways}...\end{sideways}

% ¤¤ Matematik mm. ¤¤
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,stmaryrd}       % Avancerede matematik-udvidelser
\usepackage{mathtools}                      % Andre matematik- og tegnudvidelser
\usepackage{textcomp}                       % Symbol-udvidelser (fx promille-tegn med \textperthousand)
\usepackage{siunitx}                        % Flot og konsistent praesentation af tal og enheder med \si{enhed} og \SI{tal}{enhed}
\sisetup{output-decimal-marker = {,}}       % Opsaetning af \SI og decimalseparator
%\usepackage[version=3]{mhchem}             % Kemi-pakke til flot og let notation af formler, fx \ce{Fe2O3}
%\usepackage{rsphrase}                      % Kemi-pakke til RS-saetninger, fx \rsphrase{R1}

% ¤¤ Referencer og kilder ¤¤ %
\usepackage[danish]{varioref}               % Muliggoer bl.a. krydshenvisninger med sidetal (\vref)
\usepackage[square,numbers]{natbib}
  % Udvidelse med naturvidenskabelige citationsmodeller, herunder Harvard-modellen
%\usepackage{xr}                            % Referencer til eksternt dokument med \externaldocument{<NAVN>}
%\usepackage{glossaries}                    % Terminologi- eller symbolliste (se mere i Lars Madsens Latex-bog)

% ¤¤ Misc. ¤¤ %
\usepackage{listings}                       % Placer kildekode i dokumentet med \begin{lstlisting}...\end{lstlisting}
\usepackage{lipsum}                         % Dummy tekst med fx \lipsum[2]
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}          % Muliggoer enkelt konfiguration af lister (se \setlist nedenfor)
\usepackage{pdfpages}                       % Goer det muligt at inkludere pdf-dokumenter med kommandoen \includepdf[pages={x-y}]{fil.pdf}  
\pdfoptionpdfminorversion=6                 % Muliggoer inkludering af pdf-dokumenter af version 1.6 og hoejere
\pretolerance=2500                          % Justering af afstand mellem ord (hoejt tal, mindre orddeling og mere luft mellem ord)

% Kommentarer og rettelser med \fxnote. Med 'final' i stedet for 'draft' udloeser hver note en error i den faerdige rapport.
\usepackage[footnote,draft,danish,silent,nomargin]{fixme}       


%%%% BRUGERDEFINEREDE INDSTILLINGER %%%%

% ¤¤ Marginer ¤¤ %
\setlrmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}      % \setlrmarginsandblock{Indbinding}{Kant}{Ratio}
\setulmarginsandblock{3cm}{3cm}{*}      % \setulmarginsandblock{Top}{Bund}{Ratio}
\checkandfixthelayout                       % Oversaetter vaerdier til brug for andre pakker

%   ¤¤ Afsnitsformatering ¤¤ %
\setlength{\parindent}{0mm}                 % Stoerrelse af indryk
\setlength{\parskip}{3mm}                   % Afstand mellem afsnit ved brug af double Enter
\linespread{1,1}                            % Linjeafstand

% ¤¤ Litteraturlisten ¤¤ %
%\bibpunct[,]{[}{]}{;}{a}{,}{,}                 % Definerer parametre ved Harvard-henvisning (bl.a. parantestype og seperatortegn)
\bibliographystyle{abbrvnat}            % Udseende af litteraturlisten (Harvard-metoden - skift til fx 'plain' for tal)

% ¤¤ Dybde af overskrifter ¤¤ %
\setsecnumdepth{subsection}                 % Dybden af nummerede overkrifter (part/chapter/section/subsection)
\settocdepth{subsection}                    % Dybden af overskrifter vist i indholdsfortegnelsen

% ¤¤ Lister ¤¤ %
\setlist{
  topsep=0pt,                               % Vertikal afstand mellem tekst og listen
  itemsep=-1ex,                             % Vertikal afstand mellem items
} 

% ¤¤ Visuelle referencer ¤¤ %
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}           % Danner klikbare referencer (hyperlinks) i dokumentet
\hypersetup{colorlinks = true,              % Opsaetning af farvede hyperlinks (interne links, citeringer og URL)
    linkcolor = black,
    citecolor = black,
    urlcolor = black
}

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af figur- og tabeltekst ¤¤ %
\captionnamefont{\small\bfseries\itshape}   % Opsaetning af tekstdelen ('Figur' eller 'Tabel')
\captiontitlefont{\small}                   % Opsaetning af nummerering
\captiondelim{. }                           % Seperator mellem nummerering og figurtekst
\captionstyle{\centering}                   % Justering/placering af figurteksten (centreret = \centering, venstrejusteret = \raggedright)
\captionwidth{\linewidth}                   % Bredden af figurteksten
\hangcaption                                % Venstrejusterer fler-linjers figurtekst under hinanden
\setlength{\belowcaptionskip}{0pt}          % Afstand under figurteksten

% ¤¤ Opsaetning af listings ¤¤ %
\definecolor{commentGreen}{RGB}{34,139,24}
\definecolor{stringPurple}{RGB}{208,76,239}

\lstset{language=Matlab,                    % Sprog
    basicstyle=\ttfamily\scriptsize,        % Opsaetning af teksten
    keywords={for,if,while,else,elseif,     % Noegleord at bfremhaeve
              end,break,return,case,
              switch,function},
    keywordstyle=\color{blue},              % Opsaetning af noegleord
    commentstyle=\color{commentGreen},      % Opsaetning af kommentarer
    stringstyle=\color{stringPurple},       % Opsaetning af strenge
    showstringspaces=false,                 % Mellemrum i strenge enten vist eller blanke
    numbers=left, numberstyle=\tiny,        % Linjenumre
    extendedchars=true,                     % Tillader specielle karakterer
    columns=flexible,                       % Kolonnejustering
    breaklines, breakatwhitespace=true,     % Bryd lange linjer
}

% ¤¤ Navngivning ¤¤ %
\addto\captionsdanish{
    \renewcommand\contentsname{Indholdsfortegnelse}         % Skriver 'Indholdsfortegnelse' i stedet for 'Indhold'
    \renewcommand\appendixname{Appendiks}                   % Skriver 'Appendiks' i stedet for 'Appendix'
    \renewcommand\appendixpagename{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\appendixtocname{Appendiks}
    \renewcommand\cftchaptername{\chaptername~}             % Skriver 'Kapitel' foran kapitlerne i indholdsfortegnelsen
    \renewcommand\cftappendixname{\appendixname~}           % Skriver 'Appendiks' foran appendiks i indholdsfortegnelsen
}

% ¤¤ Kapiteludssende ¤¤ %
\definecolor{numbercolor}{gray}{0.8}        % Definerer en farve til brug til kapiteludseende
\newif\ifchapternonum

\makechapterstyle{jenor}{                   % Definerer kapiteludseende frem til ...
  \renewcommand\beforechapskip{0pt}
  \renewcommand\printchaptername{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternum{}
  \renewcommand\printchapternonum{\chapternonumtrue}
  \renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\fontfamily{cmr}\fontseries{b}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{28}{38}\selectfont\raggedleft}
  \renewcommand\chapnumfont{\fontfamily{pbk}\fontseries{m}\fontshape{n}\fontsize{1in}{0in}\selectfont\color{numbercolor}}
  \renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
    \noindent
    \ifchapternonum
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{X}
    {\let\\\newline\chaptitlefont ##1\par} 
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip-2.5mm\hrule
    \else
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{Xl}
    {\parbox[b]{\linewidth}{\chaptitlefont ##1}} & \raisebox{-15pt}{\chapnumfont \thechapter}
    \end{tabularx}
    \par\vskip2mm\hrule
    \fi
  }
}                                           % ... her

\chapterstyle{jenor}                        % Valg af kapiteludseende - Google 'memoir chapter styles' for alternativer

% ¤¤ Sidehoved/sidefod ¤¤ %

\makepagestyle{Uni}                         % Definerer sidehoved og sidefod udseende frem til ...
\makepsmarks{Uni}{%
    \createmark{chapter}{left}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createmark{section}{right}{shownumber}{}{. \ }
    \createplainmark{toc}{both}{\contentsname}
    \createplainmark{lof}{both}{\listfigurename}
    \createplainmark{lot}{both}{\listtablename}
    \createplainmark{bib}{both}{\bibname}
    \createplainmark{index}{both}{\indexname}
    \createplainmark{glossary}{both}{\glossaryname}
}
\nouppercaseheads                                           % Ingen Caps oenskes

\makeevenhead{Uni}{Group}{}{\leftmark}              % Lige siders sidehoved (\makeevenhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddhead{Uni}{Group}{}{Aalborg Universitet}         % Ulige siders sidehoved (\makeoddhead{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\usepackage{lastpage}
\makeevenfoot{Uni}{}{}{Side \thepage \: af \pageref{LastPage}}                          % Lige siders sidefod (\makeevenfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})
\makeoddfoot{Uni}{}{}{Side \thepage \: af \pageref{LastPage}}                           % Ulige siders sidefod (\makeoddfoot{Navn}{Venstre}{Center}{Hoejre})


\makeheadrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}                       % Tilfoejer en streg under sidehovedets indhold
%\makefootrule{Uni}{\textwidth}{0.5pt}{1mm}                 % Tilfoejer en streg under sidefodens indhold

\copypagestyle{Unichap}{Uni}                                % Der dannes en ny style til kapitelsider
\makeoddhead{Unichap}{}{}{}                                 % Sidehoved defineres som blank på kapitelsider
\makeevenhead{Unichap}{}{}{}
\makeheadrule{Unichap}{\textwidth}{0pt}
\aliaspagestyle{chapter}{Unichap}                           % Den ny style vaelges til at gaelde for chapters
                                                            % ... her

\pagestyle{Uni}                                             % Valg af sidehoved og sidefod (benyt 'plain' for ingen sidehoved/fod)


%%%% EGNE KOMMANDOER %%%%

% ¤¤ Billede hack ¤¤ %                                      % Indsaet figurer nemt med \figur{Stoerrelse}{Fil}{Figurtekst}{Label}
\newcommand{\figur}[4]{
        \begin{figure}[H] \centering
            \includegraphics[width=#1\textwidth]{media/#2}
            \caption{#3}
            \label{#4}
        \end{figure} 
}

% ¤¤ Specielle tegn ¤¤ %
\newcommand{\dec}{^{\circ}}                                 % '\dec' returnerer et gradtegn (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\decC}{^{\circ}\text{C}}                        % '\decC' returnerer et gradtegn + 'C' (husk $$ udenfor aligns)
\newcommand{\m}{\cdot}                                      % '\m' returnerer et gangetegn


%%%% ORDDELING %%%%

\hyphenation{In-te-res-se e-le-ment}
```

Here is my main if that helps

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, fleqn, twoside, openany]{memoir}
\input{preamble}

\raggedbottom

\begin{document}

    \frontmatter
    \include{forside}                   % IKKE FÆRDIG
    \include{titelblad}                 % IKKE FÆRDIG
    \include{forord}                    % IKKE FÆRDIG
    \tableofcontents*

    \mainmatter
    \include{introduktion}              % IKKE FÆRDIG
    \include{projektbeskrivelse} 
    \include{problemAnalyse/Problemfomulering}
    \input{problemAnalyse/problemetsVigtighed}
    \input{problemAnalyse/opstodProblemet}
    \input{problemAnalyse/konsekvenser}
    \input{problemAnalyse/interessentAnalyse}
    \input{problemAnalyse/lovgivning}
    \input{problemAnalyse/eksisterendeLosninger}
    \input{problemAnalyse/mulige_loesninger} %Mangler 
    \input{problemAnalyse/kravTilLosning}

    \include{Appendix/transskriptionInterview}

\begingroup
    \raggedright
    \bibliography{bibtex/bibliography}                          % Litteraturlisten inkluderes
\endgroup










\end{document}
```

Just ignore the comments. That is just for me.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Hi. I am new in here and dont know how to insert my code without it just looking like a text file.

Comment: Just paste it, then mark it with your mouse and hit the `{}` button in the editor, alternatively place `\`\`\`` in the lines above and below your code block.

Comment: It should be in there now. Is my problem understandable?

Comment: Lastpage uses \AtEndDocument.  There is no equivalent for \frontmatter.  Place  a \label just before \mainmatter and use \pageref.

Comment: So if the last page for my frontmatter is page 4, how can I then make it page iv of iv?

Comment: I have added my main if that helps anyone.